# Python Dictionary -index numbering is different every time

Tags: python

I'm using python 2.7\ Linux

I have api result (see below):

```
{"id":"137","iv":0,
"components":[{"id":"928","type":"IDUGW","creation_date":"2016-05-04 08:10:38.0","update_date":"2016-05-04 08:10:38.0","unit_id":"137","serial_number":"00000000501C8349"},
{"id":"927","type":"IDU","creation_date":"2016-05-04 08:10:37.0","update_date":"2016-05-04 08:10:37.0","unit_id":"137","serial_number":"00000000501C8268"},
{"id":"930","type":"Battery","creation_date":"2016-05-04 08:10:40.0","update_date":"2016-05-04 08:10:40.0","unit_id":"137","serial_number":"00000000501C802A"}
,{"id":"929","type":"Panel","creation_date":"2016-05-04 08:10:39.0","update_date":"2016-05-04 08:10:39.0","unit_id":"137","serial_number":"00000000501C810B"}],
"creation_date":"2016-05-04 08:10:41.0",
"update_date":"2016-05-04 08:10:41.0",
"serial_number":"0011",
"phone_number":"972528745028",
"owner_phone":"9720545555554"}
```

if i understand it right, i have dictionary inside dictionary ( 2nd line "component" is another dictionary which has 4 key\values in it)

I'm trying to check if in dictionary the "type" equals to parameter i give.

Code:

if (MyDictionary[u'components'][0][u'type'] <> lRestParams['type4']):

i have 4 index (0,1,2,3)

sometimes the "if" pass, and sometimes the index is changed (when rebuilding everything) and it fails

how can i compare type4 to MyDictionary[u'components'][one of index][u'type']
In addition i need to compare after that that the value of the key = value4
so it means that if we check index x than key and value should be checked there.

Hope not to complicated

Thanks in advance

Ohad

Comment: The value corresponding to the key "component" is not a dictionary. It is a list, containing four dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving the index number, you can loop through the component values to do the comparision.

```
for keys in data['components']:
    if keys['type'] == "IDUGW":
        print "matched"
```

Comment: I need to compare type in json to my type.let's say i did it.than i need to compare the serial number in json to my serial number.but i need to know that serial number x is the value of type x  (i.e orange=10, apple=5)-if i found this 2 keis and values they might appear orange=5 ,apple=10).I need in the same dictionary (have 4 in total) to have type and serial number as it should be and not type in dictioary 1 and it serial numbrt in dictionary 3 for instance

Comment: You can access serial number using data['serial_number']. assuming you have only one dictionary value as you have provided. if not you can loop through the values. for example, 
for datas in data:
   for keys in data['component']:
      if keys['type'] == "IDUGW":
          print "matched"
      print data['serial_number"]